# Choosing between imputation methods

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, decision-tree, imputation

I'm trying to evaluate 2 methods for imputation of data.

My dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

My target label is `LotFrontage`.

First I encoded all categorial features with OneHotEncoding and then I used the correlation matrix and filter anything above `-0.3` or blow `0.3`.

```
encoded_df = pd.get_dummies(train_df, prefix_sep="_", columns=['MSZoning', 'Street', 'Alley',
                                                       'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities',
                                                       'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood',
                                                       'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle'])

corrmat = encoded_df.corr()
corrmat[(corrmat > 0.3) | (corrmat < -0.3)]
# filtering out based on corrmat output...
encoded_df = encoded_df[['SalePrice', 'MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea',
                         'BldgType_1Fam', 'BldgType_2fmCon', 'BldgType_Duplex', 'BldgType_Twnhs', 'BldgType_TwnhsE',
                         'MSZoning_C (all)', 'MSZoning_FV', 'MSZoning_RH', 'MSZoning_RL', 'MSZoning_RM']]
```

Then I try two imputation methods:

1. use the mean value of `LotFrontage` (used this method because I saw low outlier ratio)
2. Tried to predict `LotFrontage` with `DecisionTreeRegressor`

```
# imputate LotFrontage with the mean value (we saw low outliers ratio so we gonna use this)
encoded_df1 = encoded_df.copy()
encoded_df1['LotFrontage'].fillna(encoded_df['LotFrontage'].mean(), inplace=True)
X1 = encoded_df1.drop('LotFrontage', axis=1)
y1 = encoded_df1['LotFrontage']
X1_train, X1_test, y1_train, y1_test = train_test_split(X1, y1)
classifier1 = DecisionTreeRegressor()
classifier1.fit(X1_train, y1_train)
y1_pred = classifier1.predict(X1_test)
print('score1: ', classifier1.score(X1_test, y1_test))

# imputate LotFrontage with by preditcing it using DecisionTreeRegressor
encoded_df2 = encoded_df.copy()
X2 = encoded_df2[~encoded_df2['LotFrontage'].isnull()].drop('LotFrontage', axis=1)
y2 = encoded_df2[~encoded_df2['LotFrontage'].isnull()]['LotFrontage']
X2_train, X2_test, y2_train, y2_test = train_test_split(X2, y2)
classifier2 = DecisionTreeRegressor()
classifier2.fit(X2_train, y2_train)
y2_pred = classifier2.predict(encoded_df2[encoded_df2['LotFrontage'].isnull()].drop('LotFrontage', axis=1))
imputated_encoded_df2 = encoded_df2[encoded_df2['LotFrontage'].isnull()].assign(LotFrontage=y2_pred)
X3 = imputated_encoded_df2.drop('LotFrontage', axis=1)
y3 = imputated_encoded_df2['LotFrontage']
X3_train, X3_test, y3_train, y3_test = train_test_split(X3, y3)
classifier2.fit(X3_train, y3_train)
y3_pred = classifier2.predict(X3_test)
print('score2: ', classifier2.score(X3_test, y3_test))
```

My questions are:

1. Is it correct of me first using `fillna` with the mean value and then splitting to train and test and checking the score? Because if I'm filling the values prior to fitting the model won't it fit the model on the imputated data and thus giving me biased result? Same for the second method
2. Anything else I'm doing wrong since I can't determine the best method for imputation since I get bad and random score for both methods

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @Turing85 technically correct, but arguably not the appropriate close reason here: if OP removed their 2nd question (hence making the question focused), would this be on-topic? Probably not...

Answer (score 0):

**1.Imputation Using (Mean/Median) Values:**

This works by calculating the mean/median of the non-missing values in a column and then replacing the missing values within each column separately and independently from the others. It can only be used with numeric data.

**Pros**:

Easy and fast.

Works well with small numerical datasets.

**Cons**:

Doesn’t factor the correlations between features. 

It only works on the column level.

Will give poor results on encoded categorical features (do NOT use it on categorical features).

Not very accurate.

Doesn’t account for the uncertainty in the imputations.

**2.Imputation Using (Most Frequent) or (Zero/Constant) Values:**

Most Frequent is another statistical strategy to impute missing values and YES!! It works with categorical features (strings or numerical representations) by replacing missing data with the most frequent values within each column.

**Pros**:
Works well with categorical features.
**Cons**:
It also doesn’t factor the correlations between features.
It can introduce bias in the data.

**Zero or Constant imputation** — as the name suggests — it replaces the missing values with either zero or any constant value you specify

**3.Imputation Using k-NN:**

The k nearest neighbours is an algorithm that is used for simple classification. The algorithm uses ‘feature similarity’ to predict the values of any new data points. This means that the new point is assigned a value based on how closely it resembles the points in the training set. This can be very useful in making predictions about the missing values by finding the k’s closest neighbours to the observation with missing data and then imputing them based on the non-missing values in the neighbourhood.

**How does it work?**
It creates a basic mean impute then uses the resulting complete list to construct a KDTree. Then, it uses the resulting KDTree to compute nearest neighbours (NN). After it finds the k-NNs, it takes the weighted average of them.

**Pros**:
Can be much more accurate than the mean, median or most frequent imputation methods (It depends on the dataset).

**Cons**:
Computationally expensive. KNN works by storing the whole training dataset in memory.
K-NN is quite sensitive to outliers in the data (unlike SVM)

Since the outlier ratio is low we can use **method 3**. 
*It will also have less impact on the correlation between the imputed target variable(i.e LotFrontage) and other features.*

```
import sys
from impyute.imputation.cs import fast_knn
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) #Increase the recursion limit of the OS

# start the KNN training
train_df['LotFrontage']=fast_knn(train_df[['LotFrontage','1stFlrSF','MSSubClass']], k=30)
```

I've chosen the two features considering their correlation with the LotFrontage column.